# Does Heroku have a free option?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm using heroku to host a very simple signup form I create in Rails 3.1

I am also using delayed_job to deliver confirmation email to registered users.

I think I will be using 1 dyno and 1 worker for this. But I'm not very sure about this. Someone using heroku, please clarify about this.

Also when does the billing start.

Comment: http://www.heroku.com/pricing#0-0

Comment: @Chance I have already seen that page. I also understand the pricing, what I don't understand is that what a basic app will be using all the time, in terms of dyno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a free option, but it is very restricted, coming with a 5mb database and one "dyno" (a server for requests to your application) and no worker processes.

With one dyno and one worker your server hosting costs will be *at most* $35 a month. I say "at most" because you are able to spool up and shut down workers as you need them, meaning that you could reduce your costs by managing the uptime and downtime for your workers.

To start a worker, run this command from your computer while in the Heroku application's directory.

```
heroku workers 1
```

To stop that worker, run this command:

```
heroku workers 0
```

For more information see this page: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job

Comment: This clears my doubt exactly. My app will use delayed_job worker only when someone signs up. That mean one worker will remain jobless almost most of the time. I will have to use some other gem to fire up and down a worker on the fly.